# How many polygons under a point (ArcGIS solution preferred)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geoprocessing, point

Opposite of Point in Poly.

How many polygons underneath a point.

I have a point layer with many points.
I have a polygon layer with many polygons.

I need to add an attribute to the points that states how many of the polygons it is in
That is something like

Point 1 18 polygons
Point 2 10 polygons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) with your target features as points and join features as polygon.

For the match option, one of the within options should work (within a distance, completely within, clementini, etc.)

You can add a new field with the merge rule set to `count`, so that you'll get how many polygons are intersecting with the points.

Comment: thanks the spatial join one-to-one tool did it by adding a count field.